# Inyectar programaticamente componente en Vue 2

Tags: vue.js, buefy

quiero saber saber lo siguiente, por favor.

Estoy usando la librería *Buefy* con *Vue.js 2*. ¿Como puedo inyectar en el dom programaticamente el componente [Message](https://buefy.org/documentation/message/) de Buefy?. para poder renderizarlo mediante un metodo.

La cuestión es que quiero renderizarlo en el componente padre **App**, y no veo muy conveniente tenerlo allí y renderizarlo con `v-if`, sería ideal que los componentes hijos puedan inyectarlo según se necesite o no, y en este caso tengo un componente que lo necesita.

Muchas gracias a quien pueda ayudar

Comment: porque no un v-if? o un v-show?

Comment: Ahí lo explique ligeramente amigo, pero te doy una explicación mas detallada. Porque tengo al menos 10 vistas (componentes) de los cuales, al menos 2 necesitan enviar este `Message` a el componente padre (`App`), envío un solicitud con axios y dependiendo se su respuesta, sera redirigido a otra vista, con ese mensaje, por eso necesito que se inyecte en `App` y segundo, no me parece conveniente tenerlo allí solo para que sea usado por 2 componentes, espero haberme explicado amigo

Comment: Pero es que justamente v-if es para inyectar componentes... no hay inyeccion programatica porque el dom es virtual, no es real... por eso no termino de entender tu problema...Para no tener un monton de componentes en una sola vista es que usas una jerarquia de componentes....

Comment: Desconocía el echo de que no existía la  inyección  programatica, pero me confundió el echo de que, los componentes de Buefy como [Toast](https://buefy.org/documentation/toast) si se puedan mostrar de esta manera, no se cual mecanismo usa Buefy aqui entonces, muchas gracias por tu ayuda @gbianchi

Comment: no los inyecta.. el componente ya esta en el dom.. y seguro, adentro, tiene un v-if que al llamar al metodo open ponen en true una variable.. casi que te lo apuesto... VUE maneja un dom virtual, no hay jquery ni necesitas nada para ubicar los componentes, tienen una key y los ves como si fueran variables.. de ahi todo el tema del dom virtual.. en realidad no sabes como es el dom real (y si lo ves, te vas a querer matar es complejo)....

Comment: Vale vale, entiendo, gracias por tu explicación, de igual forma buscare la manera de tener ese Message en otro lado que no sea mi `App` component, pero que se logre mostrar incluso al matar a el componente contenedor, como ultimo recurso lo haré de esa manera mas sencilla